# Adding Labels to a Stacked Faceted Bar Chart - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add labels to a stacked bar chart that I have faceted, but the labels are not matching the actual data and are not being placed correctly. I was able to get the labels to show for a separate figure correctly, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this attempt.

The below code worked correctly for me:

```
figure1 <- ggplot(agent_q1, aes(x=Region, y = Proportion, fill = Answer, 
label = ifelse(Proportion > .1, scales::percent(Proportion), ""))) +
geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
geom_text(family = "Calibri Light", size = 5, position = 
position_stack(vjust = 0.5), check_overlap = TRUE) +
scale_fill_geico(palette = "bold") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image: Correct Image]

But when I try the below code, the labels do not show up correctly:

```
figure2 <- ggplot(agent_q2, aes(x = Region, y = Proportion, fill = 
Answer, label = ifelse(Proportion > .1, scales::percent(Proportion), 
""))) +
geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
facet_grid(vars(rows=Question)) +
scale_fill_geico(palette = "light") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
geom_text(family = "Calibri Light", size = 5, position = 
position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
coord_flip()
```

[image: Incorrect Image]

Data Example:

```
    dput(agent_q2)
structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Lakeland", 
"Other"), class = "factor"), Impression = c("Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied"), Answer = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, NA), .Label = c("Completely Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Slightly Satisfied", "Slightly Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Completely Dissatisfied"), class = "factor"), Counts = c(4L, 
25L, 22L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 1L, 15L, 30L, 24L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 
39L, 17L, 15L, 7L, 4L, 32L, 33L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 36L, 33L, 16L, 
7L, 10L, 1L, 20L, 33L, 16L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Question = c("The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", 
"The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", "The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", 
"The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", "The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", 
"The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", "The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", 
"The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", "The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", 
"The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", "The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", 
"The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", "The formal training you\nreceived in EDGE", 
"The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", "The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", 
"The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", "The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", 
"The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", "The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", 
"The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", "The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", 
"The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", "The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", 
"The in-person,\ninstructor-led training", "The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", 
"The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", "The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", 
"The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", "The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", 
"The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", "The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", 
"The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", "The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", 
"The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", "The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", 
"The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", "The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)", 
"The E-learning training\n(GU Courses)"), Proportion = c(0.0213903743315508, 
0.133689839572193, 0.117647058823529, 0.101604278074866, 0.106951871657754, 
0.106951871657754, 0.0053475935828877, 0.0802139037433155, 0.160427807486631, 
0.128342245989305, 0.0160427807486631, 0.0106951871657754, 0.0106951871657754, 
0.155080213903743, 0.20855614973262, 0.0909090909090909, 0.0802139037433155, 
0.0374331550802139, 0.0213903743315508, 0.171122994652406, 0.176470588235294, 
0.0374331550802139, 0.0160427807486631, 0.0053475935828877, 0.0427807486631016, 
0.192513368983957, 0.176470588235294, 0.0855614973262032, 0.0374331550802139, 
0.053475935828877, 0.0053475935828877, 0.106951871657754, 0.176470588235294, 
0.0855614973262032, 0.0160427807486631, 0.0053475935828877, 0.0053475935828877, 
0.0106951871657754)), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you post your data sample as `dput(data)` please? It will allow us to use your data.

Comment: @Sven I believe I have dput-ed the data correctly (see above). Just let me know if there's anything else you would need!

Comment: we would need to see what your data looks like. So therefore, we need to be able to copy/paste the **output** of the `dput` command in our script. It should look something like `structure(list...` If the data is too big, you can try with `dput(head(data))`

Comment: okay, I think I did it correctly this time

Comment: So, why do you feel this output is not correct? I've actually done the same and it looks ok. Keep in mind you are not showing labels that are below 10%. Perhaps change that value to 5% (.05) and reduce the size to 3. I've also added `hjust = 0.5` just in case.

Comment: Ah, is your problem you have 2 times the same category? Because your data actually has twice the same value as well, so that's pretty much expected.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Sven! So my two issues are: 1) some segments in the bar chart have multiple labels per segment, which in theory should not be happening, and 2) the proportions are not adding correctly (e.g. "Dissatisfied" for the middle bar should be adding to 11.8%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has 2 times the same category, so we need to fix that first:

```
library(dplyr)
agent_q2 <- agent_q2 %>%
  group_by(Answer, Question) %>%
  mutate(prop_sum = sum(Proportion))
agent_for_plot <- agent_q2[!duplicated(agent_q2[c(3,7)]),]
```

Then adjusting the shown percentages and the alignment:

```
ggplot(agent_for_plot, aes(x = Region, y = prop_sum, fill = 
                       Answer, label = ifelse(prop_sum > .05, scales::percent(prop_sum), 
                                              ""))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(vars(rows=Question)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  geom_text(family = "Calibri Light", size = 3, hjust = 0.5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

This is getting me:

[image]

Note that I don't have your color palette nor is it recognizing "Calibri Light". Also, for some reason it's not center aligning the values of the top chart... But this starts going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! Was able to modify this and get it to work!!